# I get an error when I load an excel in java

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to read a simple .xlsx in java

```
private void readExcelData(String excel) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(excel);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
}
```

but i get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but class was expected`

I had to add xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.3.0.jar or it gives me `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException`
 
Maybe it has something to do with that.

Does someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a dependency issue, find out which jar is being used. Perhaps conflicting versions of poi jar, poi-4.1.0.jar is needed and you have poi-4.0.1.jar.

```
ClassLoader classloader = org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
URL res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/poi/util/POILogger.class");
String path = res.getPath();
System.out.println("POI came from " + path);
```

If you are using maven, run "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose" to show included jars.