# Found interface org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but class was expected error

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

```
public String readExcel(String columnname,String UserType) {


        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            XSSFWorkbook wr = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sh = wr.getSheet(prop.getProperty("env"));
            int row = sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            System.out.println(row);

                for(int j=0;j<row;j++) {
                    if((sh.getRow(j).getCell(1).getStringCellValue()).equalsIgnoreCase(UserType)) {
                        for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
                            String s=sh.getRow(0).getCell(i).getStringCellValue();
                            if(s.equals(columnname)) {
                                 value = sh.getRow(0).getCell(i).getStringCellValue();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Util obj=new Util();
        obj.readExcel("Username","Testuser1");
    }
```

I am using this code to read data from Excel, but getting an exception in thread "main" `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but class was expected`.
Not sure about the reason, can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get an error when I load an excel in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730592/i-get-an-error-when-i-load-an-excel-in-java)

Comment: The `org.apache.poi.util.POILogger` was an abstract class until `apache poi 4.0.1`. Now in `apache poi 4.1.0` it is an interface. You have a mix of `apache poi` versions running. Exactly version `4.1.0` and an earlier version. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks, I was using mix version of poi..

Comment: Hey Alex Ritcher. Would you like to add your comment as the answer? It also solves my issue and I'd love to "vote" for your answer :)

Comment: I'm using 4.1.1 version and it's an interface in that version as well. How can I get rid of the exception instead of lowering the version to 4.0.1?

Answer (score 13):

Add this in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

The version of **poi-ooxml** and **poi** should be the same.

I am assuming that you already have **poi** in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.2</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.2</version>
  </dependency>

I have used still same error !!!

Comment: @TaritRay I also use 4.1.2 and has error...how you solve finally?

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when the versions of `poi` and `poi-ooxml` did not match. This caused the error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

The error went away after aligning the versions of these libraries:

```
<properties>
    <poi.version>4.1.2</poi.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.2</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.2</version>
  </dependency>

I have used still same error !!!